# how to find max. relative frequency in string, python?

Tags: python

How to find max. relative frequency in string? The function which takes a string argument and returns the highest relative frequency of any letter in the string. For example, the string 'sufficit' has 8 letters, and the most frequent letters are f and i, which both occur twice. Thus, the highest relative frequency is 2/8. The string 'Non-even' has 7 letters (- is not a letter), and the most frequent letter is n which occurs three times (one N and two n). Thus, the highest relative frequency is 3/7.

```
def max_rel_freq(string):
    dic = {}
    total = float(len(string))
    for ch in string:
        if ch in dic:
            dic[ch] = dic[ch] + 1
        else:
            dic[ch] = 1

    frequencies = []
    for s in string:
        frequencies.append(float(dic[s]/total))
    return max(frequencies)
```

This works for only 'sufficit' but does not give required output for 'Non-even'.

Comment: Are there any cases where finding the max count would not also be the max relative frequency?

Comment: check out this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/return-maximum-occurring-character-in-the-input-string/

Comment: `collections.Counter()` could be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
def max_rel_freq(string):
    max_freq = 1
    string = string.lower()
    string = list(map(str,string.strip('')))
    for i in string:
        if string.count(i)> max_freq:
            max_freq = string.count(i)
    return max_freq
```

Comment: It did not give the intended output.

Comment: can you tell me what was your input and what is the expected ans so that i can check

Comment: the string "Nåon-even3" should return value 3/7 as there are 3 n and 7 letters without using import statement. Only to count letters. should not count accented letters, numeric values, special letters...

Comment: the ans it returns is 3 only. i just checked the same